# callback has already been called for parallel processing in async.parallel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, parallel-processing, promise

I am using `async.parallel` as below, but I keep on getting "callback has already been called."

Below `browserperf` is a third party API that returns performance metrics for the current url and `config.data1.urls` is read from a JSON file that just returns an array of urls.

More information on browser-perf is here:
https://github.com/axemclion/browser-perf

```
async.parallel([

        function(callback) {
            Promise.mapSeries(config.data1.urls, function(url) { 
                var  totalTime= 0, endTime= 0;
                console.log(url);
                new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
                    browserPerf(url, function(error, data) {
                        console.log("browserPerf for ",url);

                        if (!error) {
                            resolve(data);
                            data = data[0];

                            let loadTime = (data.loadEventEnd - data.navigationStart)/1000 + ' sec';
                            let firstPaint = data.firstPaint;
                            let domInteractive = (data.domInteractive - data.navigationStart)/1000 + ' sec';

                            var perfData = {
                                'URL' : url,
                                'firstPaint' : firstPaint,
                                'loadTime' : loadTime,
                                'domInteractive' : domInteractive
                            };

                            self.dats.push(perfData);
                            console.log(self.dats);

                            endTime = Date.now();
                            totalTime += (endTime - self.startTime);
                            var ms = totalTime,
                            min = (ms/1000/60) << 0,
                            sec = (ms/1000) % 60;

                            console.log("Total time for data to be recorded: ", min + ':' + sec);

                            callback(null, self.dats);    


                          } else {
                            console.log(error);
                            reject(error);
                        }
                    }, {
                        selenium: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
                        browsers: ['chrome']
                    });
                });

            });                 
        },

        function(callback) {
            Promise.mapSeries(config.data2.urls, function(url) { 
                var  totalTime= 0, endTime= 0;
                console.log(url);
                new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
                    browserPerf(url, function(error, data) {
                        console.log("browserPerf for ",url);

                        if (!error) {
                            resolve(data);
                            data = data[0];

                            let loadTime = (data.loadEventEnd - data.navigationStart)/1000 + ' sec';
                            let firstPaint = data.firstPaint;
                            let domInteractive = (data.domInteractive - data.navigationStart)/1000 + ' sec';

                            var perfData = {
                                'URL' : url,
                                'firstPaint' : firstPaint,
                                'loadTime' : loadTime,
                                'domInteractive' : domInteractive
                            };

                            self.dats.push(perfData);
                            console.log(self.dats);  

                            endTime = Date.now();
                            totalTime += (endTime - self.startTime);
                            var ms = totalTime,
                            min = (ms/1000/60) << 0,
                            sec = (ms/1000) % 60;

                            console.log("Total time for data to be recorded: ", min + ':' + sec);  
                            callback(null, self.dats);             
                          } else {
                            console.log(error);
                            reject(error);
                        }

                    }, {
                        selenium: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
                        browsers: ['chrome']
                    });
                });

            });

        }
    ],function(err,result) {
            console.log(result);
    });
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? I just want the combined result stored in `self.dats` to be caught in the results in the callback function.

Comment: This seems pretty complicated with all of the callbacks you got going on here. Oftentimes it helps me to make a standalone example and just start adding pieces one by one. I'd suggest creating a minimum example of your issue then add more and more elements to isolate where the break is. Then update your question with where it's really happening. With everything going on it would make your question harder to answer.

Comment: What kind of promise implementation are you using? `Promise.mapSeries` isn't standard.

Comment: I've seen the comment "don't use async.js and Promises together" so many times. Perhaps the warning is justified